# How do i network ten branch office with voip, video calling and files sharing

Tags: networking

Am an IT person, have done some networking job for my organization like Lan and wireless within the area, configure windows server to manage staff account My company has ten branch (In each state) in my country and am giving a task to connect dose branch together, which there will be VOIP, Video calling and sharing of files within the branch. I need someone to help me with this project..what and what did I need to put in place

Comment: The best thing you can do now is to find a consultant in your country who can help you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by gathering more detailed requirements from what exactly your organisation wants to do!  or are they simply trying to keep up with the Jones'? In which case you could end up with an expensive system that people hate/don't use that cost a lot of money!

What may be an ok fit for your business is  [Office Communications Server (OCS)](http://www.microsoft.com/uc/en/au/products.aspx). It sounds like you're already using microsoft & have AD setup.  OCS can leverage that existing infrastructure.  Check to see if it meets your requirements for voip/video calls.  It also allows for some rudimentry file sharing.  If not then maybe sharepoint? although that is another project in itself!

Comment: Thank Nick sharhpoint also is okay but just like what you said is another project.....will are just trying make all branch look as if the are on same building.